# How to save sound after change volume of channels in pygame

Tags: pygame

I want to 'save' music after that I changed the channel volume.
My code is like this:

```
from pygame import mixer
import time

mixer.init()
sound0 = mixer.Sound('Prison.mp3')
channel0 = mixer.Channel(0)
channel0.play(sound0)
channel0.set_volume(1.0, 0.0)

time.sleep(sound0.get_length())
```

after this the music just play in left channel and in right channel nothing go to play.
Now I want to save this music. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think you should use another software to minipulate your audio file to play in left channel only

you can easily do that in [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) by following these steps:

1. open your audio file in audacity.
2. move the second slider [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAvOb.png) all the way to the left to make audio come out from left channel only.
3. export your audio.

Comment: that's true but the code that I show in my question is not the target. I want to do this with python code because after this, I can change my music name and another music go to be created.

Comment: for that you could use a command called ffmpeg to install it follow this page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/ 

after that install a python binding to use the command easier in python using:
pip install ffmpeg_python 

and here is the documentation for how you can manipulate audio channels using ffmpeg:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation


unfortunately I was able to mute left channel only hope you can figure out how to mute right channel.